# VS 2013 publish does not include all folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, publishing

I'm building a web app in VS 2013. After using the Publish functionality provided by VS, i see that one of my folders was not included in the build. 
The folder contains some Json files.

Do you, by any chance have an explanation and maybe a solution for this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gess it's becouse you just don't configure it right. In your VS project right click on json file that you need -> `Properties`:

> **Build Action**: Content
>
> **Copy to Output Directory**: Copy if newer

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is not to use the integrated publisher, instead use [InstallShield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/producer/products/software-installation/installshield-software-installer/) , [WIX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) or any other third party tool for publishing.